# Rendering a textView onto a View

Tags: android, canvas, text, view, textview

I have a class which extends [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

In that class I draw a plain white screen and would then like to draw some text over it:

I've tried this using a textView and also canvas.drawText but I'm unable to get any text to render.  Any idea what the problem is?

```
public class MyView extends View{

    Paint myPaint;
    Paint textPaint;
    Rect background;
    RelativeLayout layout;
    TextView text;

    public myView(Context context, int width, int height){

        myPaint = new Paint();        
        myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        background = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

        layout = new RelativeLayout(context);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        text = new TextView(context);
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        text.setSize(20);
        text.setText("Test");

        layout.addView(layout);

    }

   @Override
   public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

       canvas.drawRect(background, myPaint);   //This draws OK 

       layout.draw(canvas); //Text doesn't draw

       canvas.drawText("Test", 0, 0, textPaint); //This also doesn't draw

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting myPaint to both black and white and not setting textPaint color at all. Also for text paint I believe you need to set text size aswell. So change these lines:

```
textPaint = new Paint();
myPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

into this:

```
textPaint = new Paint();
textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
textPaint.setTextSize(20);
```

EDIT:

Place the origin point somewhere other than 0,0. Example:

```
canvas.drawText("Test", 100, 100, textPaint);
```

Comment: Oops re the colour, that was a typo :-) I've correct it now.  I'll try setting a size on the textPaint.  Thanks

Comment: Unforuntately, that didn't work, I still get no text @MitchDart

Comment: Can i suggest that you set your rectangle's paint color to something like Color.RED so that you can make sure that your view is getting inflated to a visible size at all?

Comment: If I change it to Colour.RED, I do indeed get an empty red screen.  Thanks

Comment: Just tested it out my self. The issue is the X, Y origin point. it cannot be 0,0 since it starts drawing above the origin point. make it something like 20, 20 or calculate the Height of the text.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks, that did work for canvas.drawText, do you have any idea why the textView doesn't work?   Thanks again

Comment: According to docs at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html, Drawing the layout wont work since the layout actually calls the onDraw function for each of its children. It wont help to draw just the layout by itself (since layout is also a view). Instead of putting it in a layout, just call its measure() and layout() function then draw the textview itself.